# Stratum protocol - problem with implementation in python

Tags: mining-pools, stratum

For a couple of days I'm trying to write simple script in python to communicate with stratum pool server. I'm using simplified code of NightMiner (https://github.com/ricmoo/nightminer/) and some testnet I've foud ( stratum+tcp://pool.bitcoincloud.net:4008), but I can't get the proper result. Maybe someone more experienced could help me. Below I show each step of my script (step, no python source code).

**1. connect to the server, authorize, get the job data**

After connecting to the server I send this requests:

```
b'{"id": 1, "method": "mining.subscribe", "params": []}\n'
b'{"params": ["testuser", "anything"], "id": 2, "method": "mining.authorize"}\n'
```

and get the following response:

```
{"id":1,"result":[[["mining.set_difficulty","deadbeefcafebabea200000000000000"],["mining.notify","deadbeefcafebabea200000000000000"]],"40000004",4],"error":null}
{"id":null,"method":"mining.set_difficulty","params":[0.01]}
{"id":null,"method":"mining.notify","params":["4ca","4128bf630f57387b00e25b419d1bb77e667e4036a7d8fee80000015600000000","01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff2503a77614048c8a145e08","122f626974636f696e636c6f75642e6e65742f0000000002062c9c04000000001976a91423e020eacd64acfe093150331d44fdbcc0c7ce0688acc2eb0b00000000001976a91400bf6d61c2a34df5a9ea338fcad188c31bb4a52388ac00000000",[],"20000000","1a02b098","5e148a8c",true]}
```

**2. get the coinbase and merkle root**

With this data and extranounce='00000000' I can build the coinbase (in byte form, but I will show as hex in this example):

```
coinbase=coinb1+extranounce1+extranounce2+coinb2
coinbase=b'01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff2503a77614048c8a145e084000000400000000122f626974636f696e636c6f75642e6e65742f0000000002062c9c04000000001976a91423e020eacd64acfe093150331d44fdbcc0c7ce0688acc2eb0b00000000001976a91400bf6d61c2a34df5a9ea338fcad188c31bb4a52388ac00000000'
```

Next thing to do is double hash the coinbase with SHA256 algo, which gives as the following bytes:

```
b'9b9c9ab0b1c92844e4fed3f895f9443fefcda5ae02cc5a8ad4444f9303081a23'
```

There is no merkle branches (merkle branches array is empty), so hash above is our merkle root.

**3. building the header**

With merkle root and data received in step 1, I can start building a header:

```
header= version + prevhash + merkle root + ntime + nbits + nonce
```

I use the values as follows:

```
version - received '20000000', after little-endian conversion it is '00000020'
prevhash - received '4128bf630f57387b00e25b419d1bb77e667e4036a7d8fee80000015600000000', after conversion it is '63bf28417b38570f415be2007eb71b9d36407e66e8fed8a75601000000000000' (reverse bytes order every 4 bytes)
merkle root - get '9b9c9ab0b1c92844e4fed3f895f9443fefcda5ae02cc5a8ad4444f9303081a23' in step 2, stays that way
ntime - received '5e148a8c', after conversion it is '8c8a145e'
nbits - received '1a02b098', after conversion it is '98b0021a'
```

So the header is

```
b'0000002063bf28417b38570f415be2007eb71b9d36407e66e8fed8a756010000000000009b9c9ab0b1c92844e4fed3f895f9443fefcda5ae02cc5a8ad4444f9303081a238c8a145e98b0021a' + nonce
```

**4. search nonce**

the difficulty is 0.01, so my target is

```
00000063ff9c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

after some calculations, I find this 4 bytes to use it as a nonce:

```
b'd0cf1040'
```

so my complete header is now

```
b'0000002063bf28417b38570f415be2007eb71b9d36407e66e8fed8a756010000000000009b9c9ab0b1c92844e4fed3f895f9443fefcda5ae02cc5a8ad4444f9303081a238c8a145e98b0021ad0cf1040'
```

after double-hashing it with SHA256 algo and reverse bytes order I get this hash:

```
000000032f201567fc4d02fa468bf2dc6a5c21ae70098c124e99ee7d2520ca26
```

which is below my target, so 'd0cf1040' should be the correct nonce.

**5. submit nounce**

last thing to do is submitting the results, so I send this request to the server:

```
b'{"id":2, "method":"mining.submit","params":["testuser","4ca","00000000","5e148a8c","d0cf1040"]}\n'
```

and this is response I get:

```
{"id":2,"result":false,"error":null}
```

I have no idea why I get result=false. I can only suppose there is a mistake in step 3 (building header) and this mistake is related to byte-order of some values, but I can't find this mistake (I have tried many variants of byte-order, but never get the response result=true).

I will be much obliged if anyone can check this calculations and give me some tips.

Comment: Nonce, not nounce.

Answer (score 0):

There is (at least) one mistake:

> There is no merkle branches (merkle branches array is empty), so hash
>   above is our merkle root

The merkle array for that specific job is not empty. It contains the following branches:

```
["12ae2555f80b865bac89fa3aeb4df41b730422670fb80d1a0536276b481fab53","e1f7983af4815cb2116f16c6af916f0a139ad5a7588fd029572c6e403f9fed5d","6d5861e558d057993fdae3007ff5b49807d6f43b218e1ef85ed81223747278f1","847e7a24328302a2a8dbdad177d44d5a20916a0ba36edf2dc667c01a09da298c"]
```

Then the proper way of calculating merkle root would be required.

Comment: Thank you. You were correct, the merkle array was not empty. I have run the script again, get another job (this time, merkle array was empty) and get the same result, I mean result=false. I have edited my first post and use this new values (with empty merkle array)

Comment: how about byte-swap the nonce you found for submission?

Comment: I check the original sourcecode of NightMiner, you're right: nonce should be send to server as reversed byte-order. I changed my script and now it submits the nonce in reversed byte-order, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get it done.

There were two kind of errors I have found (not to mention the byte-order during submitting result - thank you @Charlie for that tip):

**1. the result (false) I got as the last response from the pool server was not response to 'mining.submit' method**

In my example communication log (question) I paste (among others) those requests:

```
b'{"params": ["testuser", "anything"], "id": 2, "method": "mining.authorize"}\n'
```

and

```
b'{"id":2, "method":"mining.submit","params":["testuser","4ca","00000000","5e148a8c","d0cf1040"]}\n'
```

You can see I have used the same "id" value (2) for both of this requests. So when I got the response:

```
{"id":2,"result":false,"error":null}
```

I have assumed this is "false" response to my 'mining.submit' request. But later I use individual id for each request and find out that this "false" result is response to 'mining.authorize' method. So my first problem was the authorization problem, not the nonce calculation/submitting.

I don't have any idea why I get response to 'mining.authorize' request after some other request, but this is some improvement ;)

**2. wrong data submitting in 'mining.authorize' method**

In my example communication log (question) I paste this request:

```
b'{"params": ["testuser", "anything"], "id": 2, "method": "mining.authorize"}\n'
```

But according to https://pool.bitcoincloud.net/ I should use as username '  your address (testnet address on test pools)'. So I changed this request to:

```
b'{"params": ["2N16oE62ZjAPup985dFBQYAuy5zpDraH7Hk", "anything"], "id": 2, "method": "mining.authorize"}\n'
```

Now it works, after submitting the result ('mining.submit' method) i got this response:

```
b'{"id":3,"result":true,"error":null}\n'
```

The only thing I need to figure out is why I get the response to 'mining.authorize' request as a response for some other request (the next one after 'mining.authorize' request). Any help would be appreciated.